# PHP validation for matching multiple lines using preg_match()

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have the following code snippet where I want to match supplied input by the user to match any input other that specified in the regular expression. Everything is working fine but \n part, where I want to allow multiple line. And this in particular is not working.

```
if(preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9., \/-\n]/", $addr))
    {
    echo "Invalid user input  ";
    exit;
    }
```

I am getting the message

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 17 in ......
```

Friends tell me how to allow multiple lines here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `m` (multiline) modifier in your regex..

```
preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9., \/-]/m", $addr)
                                ^
```

Comment: then still can I keep \n  part? as I thought it will allow multiline.

Comment: you can.. but it wont be useful.. also you can change ` ` (space) to `\s`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[^A-Za-z0-9., \/\n-]
```

as `-` before `\n` creates an invalid range (*- Text range out of order* issue).

If you want to allow multiple lines, just remove `\n`:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9., \/-]
```

Comment: removing \n will not serve my purpose. As I mentioned without \n it is working fine. But I need to allow multiple lines as well.

Comment: I am afraid that is not logical: you can't eat an egg and have it. When you put `\n` into the range, a user will not be able to type it. `m` option will be useless if you cannot type a newline.